# Vaadin web app stops responding until I clear browser data or use Chrome incognito

Tags: tomcat, caching, web-applications, push, vaadin

I have a Vaadin web app (Servlet version 3.0 with Websocket Push) that I compile into a war file and deploy on Tomcat 8 (on a Linux 64-bit RHEL 6 webserver). I then use Google Chrome on my home network to try to connect to it.

**Description**

- After a fresh deployment, using Google Chrome to connect to it, the app works fine (and is perfectly responsive) for the first 15-20 minutes of use.
- After that, it stops responding. The reload bar gets stuck, and trying to reconnect to the page doesn't work (new tab, new browser instance). Chrome is stuck on "Waiting for (host)...".
- When I clear browsing data (all of it), I can connect to the web app like normal. Also, if I use Chrome Incognito mode (with no browsing history), the web app works fine. The same is true for Firefox

**Attempted solutions in Tomcat**

I tried adding the following parameters to Tomcat Context.xml:

```
<Context cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize ="0" cacheTTL="1">
```

**Attempted solutions in Vaadin**

- I tried connecting to my webapp with the ?restartApplication option for Vaadin
- I tried the 3 different implementations of Push (Websocket, long polling, streaming)
- I tried disabling Push

None of my attempted solutions worked. Does anybody have any ideas? Am I mismanaging the user state that Vaadin stores?

**edit**

Forgot to mention, there are no traces of exceptions or bad behavior in the Tomcat logs. In fact there's just no output after the web app stops responding.

**another edit**

I forgot to mention that the webserver is behind a load balancer (Google Compute Engine). A friend just suggested that maybe there's a problem with the load balancer and expired cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I received a suggestion from the Vaadin forums:

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9551763/9568195